# ECR and JFROG INTEGRATION

Tags: integration, artifactory, amazon-ecr, jfrog-container-registry

Getting the below error while integrating jfrog with ecr repository in the option jfrog remote repository

> Error testing pull replication config: Unable to identify target URL as an Artifactory instance: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Giving ECR url as - https://940810086075.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/docker-lambda-testapp

Giving username as AWS and giving the token with below command
aws ecr get-authorization-token

Giving ECR url as - https://940810086075.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/docker-lambda-testapp

Giving username as AWS and giving the token with below command
aws ecr get-authorization-token

Answer (score 0):

Looking at how the remote repository feature in Artifactory works, my assumption is that this would be an issue with authN.

ECR is a multi-tenant registry which uses AWS credentials for access to specific repos. 'Bad Request', without context, makes me think it might be looking to pull a token via the OCI endpoints, which doesn't work with ECR.

It is probably worth a ping with Jfrog to see what they think, this is just me guessing. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for comment Jesse ,  I guess you are correct the auth process or the URL format is wrong that's what I want to know what is the  exact URL we use and we need to give AWS access key or ecr key

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, it seems that you tried to create a *pull replication* from ECR.
Replication is done only between Artifactory instances, you cannot create replication from a target instance that is not Artifactory.
This is also documented [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Replication#RepositoryReplication-PullReplication).

The alternative is to create a remote repository (not replication) to ECR and download artifacts from ECR through Artifactory on demand.

Comment: Thanks for your time to answer this 
But when I am adding the remote repository also I am getting the same error 
Seems I am not putting the exact url and auth process

Comment: Is this happening when you click on the test button? Try to enable bypass HEAD requests on the repository configuration (might be under the advanced tab).
Once done, try to pull an image, it is possible that the TEST button will still fail but pulling images will succeed.
There is also artifactory-request-out.log which can assist with understanding why it fails.